# TFS 2010 and SCVMM to manage snapshots

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, team-foundation-server, snapshot, scvmm

I have a VM with TFS 2010 and SCVMM 2008 installed on (I know you're told not to do that). I have SCVMM linked to the host and that's working good, and have configured the scvmm on the lab management tab on TFS.

My question is, how can you take/roll back snapshots automatically?

ie

1. install base
2. take snapshot
3. install patch
4. run tests
5. take snapshot
6. go back to snapshot taken at step 2

Thanks in advance.

Is this possible? Or should I implement this with a CodedUI Test? Or do I need visual stuido professional test manager?